# How to use two different menu in two different module with zend_navigation?

Tags: php, zend-framework, menu, module

I made an application with two modules. Each modules have its own menu. I use Zend_navigation to render the menu. The menu render correctly, the submenu either, but only one menu render on every pages. I try some fix found on this forum, but nothing changed.

Here my structure:

```
application/
    modules/
        default/
            configs/
               navigationSite.xml
            controllers/
            models/
            views/
               bootstrap.php
        cards/
            configs/
               navigationCards.xml
            controllers/
            models/
            views/
               bootstrap.php
```

Boostrap module Default:

```
<?php

class Default_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{

    protected function _initNavigation()
    {

            // read navigation XML and initialize container
            $configSite = new Zend_Config_Xml(
                                    APPLICATION_PATH.
                                        '/modules/default/configs/navigationSite.xml', 
                                        'site');
            $containerSite = new Zend_Navigation($configSite);
            // register navigation container
            $registrySite = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
            $registrySite->set('Zend_NavigationSite', $containerSite);
            // add action helper
            Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(
                new Bravo_Controller_Action_Helper_NavigationSite()
            );
    }

}
```

Boostrap module Cards:

```
<?php

class Cards_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{

    protected function _initNavigation()
    {

            // read navigation XML and initialize container
            $configCards = new Zend_Config_Xml(
                                    APPLICATION_PATH.
                                        '/modules/default/configs/navigationCards.xml', 
                                        'site');
            $containerCards = new Zend_Navigation($configCards);
            // register navigation container
            $registryCards = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
            $registryCards->set('Zend_NavigationApp', $containerCards);
            // add action helper
            Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(
                new Bravo_Controller_Action_Helper_NavigationApp()
            );
    }

}
```

navigationCards.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configData>
    <cards>
        <menu1>
            <label>Cards 1</label>
            <uri>/cards/menu1</uri>
        </menu1>
        <menu2>
            <label>Cards 2</label>
            <uri>/cards/menu2</uri>
        <menu2>
    </cards>
</configData>
```

navigationSite.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configData>
    <site>
        <menu1>
            <label>Site 1</label>
            <uri>/default/menu1</uri>
        </menu1>
        <menu2>
            <label>Site 2</label>
            <uri>/default/menu2</uri>
        <menu2>
    </site>
</configData>
```

In my view Default:

```
<div id="menu">
    <?php echo $this->navigation(Zend_Registry::get('Zend_NavigationSite'))->menu();?>
</div>
```

In my view Cards:

```
<div id="menu">
    <?php echo $this->navigation(Zend_Registry::get('Zend_NavigationApp'))->menu()
    ->renderMenu(null, array(
        'minDepth' => null,
        'maxDepth' => 1,
        'ulClass' => 'navigation',
        'onlyActiveBranch' => false));
    ?>
</div>
```

Something prevents rendering the two differents menus on its own pages, but I can't figure. Maybe someone will see the obvious :-)

EDIT: I fixed it! I just didn't know what was "Zend_Registry". Now, I'm calling the right index and all's right! :-) 
I updated the code of this post too.
Thanks guys for the alternate solutions!

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I can show how to make different menu in different modules with one bootstrap. I use a controller plugin in a project:

```
class Application_Plugin_Menu extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $module = strtolower($request->getModuleName());
        $controller = strtolower($request->getControllerName());

        $nav = new Zend_Navigation(new Zend_Config_Ini($config, $module));
        Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Navigation', $nav);   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually have more than one menu in my projects but I use only one Bootstrap with a switch in it.

Base on the "account role" I get a different menu and a different layout but in a different way:

```
protected function _initNavigationAndLayout(){
    $this->bootstrap('layout');
    $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
    $view = $layout->getView();
    switch ($examplevar){
        default:
        case 1:
            $layout->setLayout('layout1');
            $config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation1.xml','nav');
            break;
        case 2:
            $layout->setLayout('layout2');
            $config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation2.xml','nav');
            break;
    }
    $navigation = new Zend_Navigation($config);
    $view->navigation($navigation)->setAcl($this->_acl)->setRole($this->_auth->getStorage()->read()->role    );
}
```

you can see that I have a $this->_acl and a $this->_auth that are instances of Zend_Acl and Zend_Auth for permission related stuff :)

My Navigation (a sample of it):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configdata>
        <nav>
            <login>
                <label>Login</label>
                <controller>secure</controller>
                <action>login</action>
                <route>default</route>
                <resource>login</resource>
            </login>
        </nav>
    </configdata>
```